# Can I set name of an S3 bucket created in a cfn template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

The docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html) don't specify how to set the name of the bucket. Is it possible to do in a cfn template?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify the BucketName as a property like so:

```
"Resources" : {
  "bucketresource" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
    "Properties" : {
      "BucketName" : "stack-with-pictures"
    }
  }
}
```